# Access private in javascript implementation

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to access a private variable from a implementation pattern.

```js
 var d = (function(){
     
  var jsData;

  function init(){
    _bind();
    _initilise();
  }

  function _bind(){
    console.log('..inbind..');
  }

  function _initilise(){
    jsData = `data data`;
    console.log('..in_initilise..' + jsData);
  }

  return {
    init : init,
    jsData : jsData
  };
})( 
  $(document).ready ( function(){
    d.init();
    console.log(d.jsData);
  })
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The output: console.log('..in_initilise..' + jsData); : ..in_initilise..data data.
The output: console.log(d.jsData); is always 'undefined'

The last one is confusion as I am setting value in _initilise() then why it is undefined?

Comment: Is this really the code you tested ? If so you may be using d before you initialize it (depending on the initial ready state). And the your code looks like it's intentionally made confusing (and your messed indentations didn't help).

Comment: The property `jsData` in the object you return isn't a pointer to the local variable `jsData`, it's a copy of the value that the local variable had at the time you created and returned the object, which was `undefined`. If you want read-only access to the local variable the easiest way is to use a getter that returns its value.

Comment: @DenysSéguret yes I am testing the same code, also I tried to move the $(document).ready down but result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var jsData;` It declared as **primitive value**.

When IIFE is called,it return `jsData` value defined during initialisation. `i.e. undefined.`

Now,even you are updating value,its not updating the returned copy of `jsData`.

So,it remain `undefined`

**Solution :**

Defined getter to get the value of `jsData` inside closure instead returning it directly .

```
 function getData(){
          console.log(jsData);
      }
```

And

```
return {
    init : init,
    getData : getData
  };
```

Call

```
d.getDate();
```

**OR**

Define `jsData` as an object with `value` as property and update `value` property.

Because of reference ,you always have updated copy.

```
  var jsData={
    value : null
  };
```

**_initilise**

```
function _initilise(){
    jsData.value = 'data data';
    console.log('..in_initilise..' , jsData.value);
  }
```

Comment: Bravo, that was excellently the  thing missing, I made the change and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The property `jsData` in the object you return isn't a pointer to the local variable `jsData`, it's a copy of the value that the local variable had at the time you created and returned the object, which was `undefined`. If you want read-only access to the local variable you can define a getter for it that returns its value, like this:

```
var retObj = {
  init : init
}

Object.defineProperty(retObj, 'jsData', {
  configurable: false,
  get: function() { return jsData; }
});

return retObj;
```